# Rotate camera around object, ease on change position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

This question seems rather popular, but none of my searches appear to solve my issue.

I have a tower, which is building itself block by block. I want to have a camera, circling around the currently building block, and when the next block is about to be placed, translate the camera vertically, or in whatever direction needed, so the center of the rotation (in 3D space) is always that cube.

I have currently this code, but after few blocks, it does not keep it's current angle of view and the movement is just a big jump. Note that the position changes by 1 in any direction.

Here is the code:

```
transform.position = targetPosition + (transform.position - targetPosition).normalized * orbitDistance;
transform.RotateAround(targetPosition, Vector3.up, orbitSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When moving to a new position you cannot move immediately.  Your description says when block is about to be pace you want to change center which causes a jump.  Instead you want a time for change to occur change (an acceleration) where the center point moves from old center to new center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a camera boom technique here.

First, have a gameobject that represents the camera's "focus point", the point that the camera is always facing and rotating around. Call it `Focus Point`. Then, have a child of `Focus Point` that will hold the camera component. Call it `Camera`. They would have this relationship.:

```
├──Focus Point
│   └── Camera
```

The `Camera` gameobject should be rotated and positioned so that it is facing the position of `Focus Point`. This shouldn't needed to be done in code, since all you're doing will be changing the rotation and position of `Focus Point` to adjust the camera. A script like this could be attached to `Focus Point`:

```
public class FocusPointScript : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public Vector3 targetPosition;
    public float translateSpeed = 0.1f;
    public float rotateSpeed = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
        targetPosition = transform.position;
    }
  
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, 
                translateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Rotate(0f, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }
}
```

And if you want to adjust how far the camera is from the focus point, you can change the position of `Camera` forward or backward **or** (I would not do both) change the `localScale` of `Focus Point`:

```
float moveDelta = 0f; 
// calculate how to adjust
cameraGameObject.transform.Translate(moveDelta * Vector3.forward);
```

**or**

```
float scaleFactor = 1f; 
// calculate how to adjust
focusPointGameObject.transform.localScale = 
        scaleFactor * focusPointGameObject.transform.localScale;
```